# How can I remove the black line on these paths while keeping the red line?

Tags: d3.js

As the title says, I want to edit this code so that only the red lines stay and the black lines are removed. Does anyone know how to do that? I've included a screenshot of what the graph looks like now.

`

```
<script>
    var nodeData = [
        {id: "Midwives",       position: [100, 25],   parentPosition: [100, 25] },
        {id: "Nurses",   position: [25, 175],   parentPosition: [100, 25] },
        {id: "More Nurses",   position: [175, 175],  parentPosition: [100, 25] }];


     
    //Link generator with .source and .target set
    var link = d3.linkVertical()
        .source(d => d.parentPosition)
        .target(d => d.position)

    //Creating path elements by adding in our data and calling link
    d3.select("#demoSrcTar")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(nodeData)
        .join("path")
        .attr("d", link)
        .style('opacity', 0.5)
        //.classed("link", true)
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 5)
        .transition().duration(2000).attr("stroke", "red");`
```

[image]

I tried searching online and even tried ChatGPT for help. I've also tried removing random parts but I can't figure that out.

Comment: Use `.style("fill", "none")`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That worked!!

https://i.imgur.com/MzNlTFB.png

Comment: If you would like to post an answer I would accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but this is certainly a duplicate.